# An old question is closed as unclear. It gets used as a dupe target. There is a much better target available. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

While trying to close a question about a common misconception, I initially found a dupe target at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043207 - call this question A.

After some more effort, I found a much better target: [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/) - call this question B. I replaced my link in the original question, to point at B instead.

Normally, I would try to contribute to the general site cleanup effort, by a) closing A as a duplicate of B (since I have a relevant dupe-hammer), and b) possibly voting to delete it - to avoid it cluttering the results, and hopefully make it a tiny bit more likely that B will come up instead. (It didn't for me, despite the upvotes on the question, and despite the fact that I was searching for a few keywords that are all in that question's title after stemming).

However, it turns out that A was already closed at the time (under an older set of closure reasons). I cannot re-close it as a duplicate, and I am warned about voting to delete it because of the upvoted answers - even after fixing other questions to use B as a dupe-target instead.

How should I handle this situation?

---

<sub>For those finding this question later: the canonical duplicate, as of this edit, is in fact a separate question C: [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/). A was deleted, and B became a duplicate of C. I have been busying myself with redirecting some duplicates - there are a **lot**, and there are a *few* other related questions that should get used for other stuff.</sub>

Comment: Looks loke you probably did the best thing you could - asking on meta. If enough people agree with you, it will likely result in reopening and reclosure as a duplicate of the better Q&A. At a cursory glance, B does look better than A, vut since I am not an SME - deferring to others.

Comment: Well you can try to improve question A so it isn't that unclear anymore and a good sign post, then close it as dupe of B (when it got reopened first, of course). This avoids the need to delete the question and it preserves the answers which are positively received.

Comment: You can do that but it may be simpler to just leave the comment -- if you do that, normally the dupe-searchers know the existence of the "linked" tab on the right, which lists the (usually sorted by score) questions that is linked from that one, and easily pick the best...

Comment: Completely agree on this one. B has much more info than A and in general is higher quality. I reopened A and closed it as a dupe of B.

Comment: @richardec you should post this as an answer since it appears to have resolved this.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine what's an SME (in this context)? As a non-native speaker I always have to ask for this kind of abreviations so I can expand my vocabulary :)

Comment: Sorry, that was a jargonism :) SME is Subject Matter Expert, usually referred here to a person with relevant expertise, @S.Dre.

Comment: Thanks @OlegValteriswithUkraine, the more I know!

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I *am* a SME, but the automatic warning from the site when I moved to delete the question gave me pause.

Comment: In the first comment you mentioned deferring because you aren't a SME. There are other reasons, to be deferential too. I wasn't particularly trying to ping you so much as just indicate the flow of the discussion, sorry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I completely agree with this one. B has much more info than A and in general is higher quality. As I have the dupe-hammer, I reopened A and closed it as a dupe of B.

Comment: Maybe also delete A so it doesn't get used as targeet anymore.

Comment: @Braiam People with hammer should be smart enough, no point doing that I think. (although probably no harm deleting either except taking meta people's effort, low view count)

Comment: I'd definitely vote to delete A once it's been closed for a while. While its answers are fine, the question itself is very poor, IMO.

Comment: @user202729 I prefer not to give the chance to not be smart enough :)