# Is it ok to list related questions at the end of my question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it ok to place links to related questions at the end of my question using "related to" notices? Or it is bad practice on SO?

I have some questions about one big problem, and I separate questions into multiple concrete and detailed specified questions, and ask these questions one by one.

I've included an example below, is it good behavior on SO or not?

[image: Screenshot of the end of a deleted question post with a horizontal rule separating the end of the question body from a list of 3 links to other Stack Overflow questions below, each marked "related to" the question at hand]

Comment: Provided each question is well asked, on-topic, and complete in it's *own right*, yes. Please don't fall into traps like writing your qusetions like they are a series. For example, don't start a second question with something like "Following on from my last question *excludes important information as it's in the last question*" and don't give your questions titles like "Building a computer out of a potato - Part 1", "Building a computer out of a potato - Part 2", etc.

Comment: What is the intention of the "related to" links? Are they needed to understand the question? Are they relevant for anyone else encountering the question? Are they just your own "I came up with these during one of my tasks" bookkeeping?

Comment: If you have *one* question, why have you put it into a numbered list..?

Comment: FWIW, the example doesn't look like a good question to begin with. It seems to ask for opinions and is rather difficult to read. Whether related questions make sense *on that question* is something entirely different from whether related questions make sense *in general*.

Comment: Also, please don't use images of text; the above text should be posted as *text* within a quoteblock.

Comment: It it just example, and I not wanted to check mentioned question. but at the end I found the pure related question is not good on SO

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Related questions aren't necessarily bad, for example various Python canonicals link to similar questions that cover special cases (e.g. doing something without or without preserving order).

Comment: It is irrelevant to your question that a particular other question is related to your question. And it is not helpful to tell us that it is related. Put what is needed to ask your question in your post. Do not put what is not needed. Do not expect readers to read something else & then guess what is relevant & why it is relevant. Paraphrase and/or quote exactly & only what is needed for you to ask your question; format a quote as a quote; give credit to the author & source according to the [help]; & clearly use what you included to ask your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing old questions to add links to similar ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863/editing-old-questions-to-add-links-to-similar-ones)

Comment: I would avoid adding the related questions, add possible & concise information about challenge you faced & how to replicate, add reference if needed. In my experience adding the related questions might attract duplicate flags even when question is not duplicated or answered before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's an exceptionally poor question.

First of all, it's asking for best practices, which are often opinion-based, thus off-topic. This is likely the main reason people may downvote, vote to close and delete it.

Secondly, it does not explain *how* these questions are related. Just linking another question doesn't add anything useful. Just linking a bunch of questions is considered noise and may cause others to edit it out.

Linking related questions is often not informative, as questions need to be minimal and self-contained. There are exceptions, such as "I've tried xxx as suggested in some related question, but it doesn't work because ...."

Comment: So related question is only valid, when I describe cause of relation. am I right?

Comment: And they're directly relevant to the question. That's the most important thing. Just being similar or related to the same task is not enough. If you've split up a task in multiple, independent subtasks, it's often not relevant that they are related. So in nearly all cases, it's best to omit them.