# Is there any reason to keep a self answered question about an issue with beta software now resolved in the release version?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

While working on some code using some new APIs in a beta release of Xcode 15 and iOS 17, I came across a bug and an ugly workaround. So I posted a question and a self-answer based on the issue and my workaround. The question has one upvote and the answer has none. The answer has a couple of comments.

The issue I ran into has now been resolved with the release candidate version of Xcode and iOS. So my question/answer really has no more value since no one should still be using the older beta software. Apple doesn't allow developers to use beta tools to submit apps to the App Store. Apple won't allow new installations of iOS beta on devices once the beta process is over. Sure, some rare users may keep a beta version around but it's pointless.

Is there any reason why I should not delete my question and self-answer given its level of usefulness at this point?

I fully agree, in general, that questions about issues related to using beta software have value. But my one question/answer in this case has a very limited shelf life due to the specific nature of the tools involved.

Comment: Yes; Your question serves a purpose. Besides neither the question or answer is eligible to be deleted

Comment: "since no one should still be using the older beta software". But what if someone does, for whatever reason and they experience the same bug? It's a big *if*, but they'll be very glad to find out that their issue is a known bug. There's no real harm in keeping the question around.

Comment: As mentioend by the previous commenters, it still has value for whoever uses that beta version for whatever reason. Only thing I would do is edit my answer to mention that the workaround isn't necessary if people upgrade the software.

Comment: I originally wrote my question to be a bit general. But now I realize that was a mistake. I have now updated my question with more specific details about the software involved and more specific reasons why I think my question has no more use to anyone in this specific case.

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that the duplicate is *also* about XCode/iOS and thus *also* about enforced shelf life. As someone who does maintain some ancient stuff but works on an Apple device, IMO there *really is* a difference between software meant for the ages (as in many Linux cases and in general) and software aggressively culled to stay fresh (as in many Apple cases). It's unfortunate that in both Q&A the specific case is used but addressed for the general case.

Answer (score 4):

Please leave information in place about "legacy" systems, whether they're for older versions, for betas that got fixed, etc. etc. You never know when someone else will end up needing to use that version for some obscure reason. The banks still run on COBOL, after all.

Consider [explicitly linking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863) your question to a corresponding question about the release version, if there is a sensible one. That could help people who have a question about the release version and find your question from a search engine. However, if the underlying problem is really only applicable to the beta, then there is nothing to do here. Your information about an "outdated" system can't do harm, because it won't be found by people using the release version (since they *won't encounter a problem*), and therefore those people won't be misled trying to fix a phantom problem.

Comment: I've updated my question with more specific details (I should have included those details originally). I agree with your answer in general but I'm not still quite convinced it applies in my specific case.